# Javascript cycling through an object array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to use JavaScript to cycle through an array of objects

```
console.log($scope.filteredItems);
```

returns an array of 10 objects in the console

```
Object {editionId: "6", detailId: "10"} 
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
6: Object
7: Object
8: Object
9: Object
length: 10
__proto__: Array[0]
```

It's current selection is 10

I want to cycle through this filtered array using prev and next buttons

html

```
<$scope.filteredItems/{{prevItem}}" class="btn btn-left">&lt;</a>
<$scope.filteredItems/{{nextItem}}" class="btn btn-right">&gt;</a>
```

be aware that this is a filtered array from a database and incrementing may just cycle through the 
entire database not the filtered array

here's my effort

```
if ($scope.filteredItems.detailId > 0) {

    console.log($route.params);
    $scope.prevItem = Number($scope.filteredItems.detailId)-1;
} else {
    $scope.prevItem = $scope.data.products.length-1;
}

if ($scope.filteredItems.detailId < $scope.data.products.length-1) {
    $scope.nextItem = Number($scope.filteredItems.detailId)+1;
} else {
    $scope.nextItem = 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you prefixing your variables with `$` in JavaScript? That is more a PHP thing. In JQuery, you generally prefix JQuery objects with `$`, so the use of that symbol for general variables is confusing

Comment: its angular js $scope   but its more a general query   replace $scope.filtereditems with banana

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

HTML:

```
<button id="prev">Prev</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>

<div id="data_value"></div>
```

JS code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var counter = 0;
    var arrObj = [{name:"sam1",age:20},{name:"sam2",age:22},{name:"sam3",age:24},{name:"sam4",age:26},{name:"sam5",age:28}];
    var totalcounter = 0;

    for (i in arrObj) {
        totalcounter++;
    }

    $("#data_value").text(arrObj[0].name+" - "+ arrObj[0].age);
    $("#prev").attr('data-rel',counter);
    $("#next").attr('data-rel',counter);

    $("#next").click(function(){
        if (counter < totalcounter - 1) {
            ++counter;
            $("#data_value").text(arrObj[counter].name+" - "+ arrObj[counter].age);
        }
    });

    $("#prev").click(function(){
        if (counter > 0) {
            --counter;
            $("#data_value").text(arrObj[counter].name+" - "+ arrObj[counter].age);
        }
    });       
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this Just tried in jsfiddle and the data_value is not been returned

Comment: Thansk Sandeep your a star , cool this works so if i use var arrObj = $scope.filteredItems will this work  ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to loop through an array of length LEN in direction DIR = +1 | -1, from PREV to NEXT position do:

```
NEXT = (PREV + DIR + LEN) % LEN
```